# \bibliographystyle{unsrtnat} with alphabetical order

Tags: bibtex

I'm using `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}` because of that (author, year) output reference style. Anyway in my bibliography the references dont appear in alphabetical order and either in the format that I need is last author name, first author name, year, title, other information's e.g.:

Author: Cristiano Ronaldo
Book title: I'm the best player in the world
year: 2013
edition: 1st
...

The format that I need is: Ronaldo, C. 2013, **I'm the best player in the world**, first edition, etc...

Anyone can help me?

Comment: This modification is really hard to establish with the given bst-style. Is `biblatex` an option for you?

Comment: With `plainnat` you get alphabetical order.

Comment: everything is a option if I could get that format of reference in text and format of bibliography

Comment: As egreg says, `plainnat` is alphabetical, but it's not at all clear if that simple switch is an answer or not.